# How to implement click listener in recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-recyclerview

I am new in android and learning about RecyclerView. I am working with json so that i can get data from server. I followed [this](http://androidcss.com/android/fetch-json-data-android/) tutorial for this. I am not getting how to implement onclicklistner on my recyclerview.

Comment: on which view you want  onClicklistner ?

Comment: I want that when ever i click on List , I should get the name of particular item clciked

Comment: That i know i am asking about view like button , Textview etc ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following your tutorial, on the "bind data" method you can set a click listener. It will as easy as writing:

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        // write your code here
        }

    });
```

You will also need to change the

```
int position
```

to `final`, like:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder,final int position) {
```

Comment: and i also want to get value when i click on list

Comment: The `int position` refers to the position of the clicked list item, if that is what you mean. If you want to show Toast, you can do this:
`Toast.makeText(context, String.valueOf(position), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`

Comment: You should know the name of the item on each position. `Toast.makeText(context, current.fishName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();` should work, if you also define that `current` as `final`

Answer (score 0):

[Item click listeners for RecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32338910/item-click-listeners-for-recyclerview)

See the answer

you should use ItemClickSupport library :

```
    ItemClickSupport.addTo(recyclerView)
            .setOnItemClickListener(new ItemClickSupport.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClicked(RecyclerView recyclerView, int position, View v) {
               /* do your thing */
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
       holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
              //TODO
            }
        }
   }
```

Comment: How do i get value in toast?

Comment: Please explain your answer with little description to help user understand better

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about onItemClickListener of `ListView` , unfortunately there is no such method in `RecyclerView`. What you can do is, give an id to your parent view of `RecyclerView` item, and set an `onClickListener`  on that in `onBindViewHolder`.