# using onClick to open details depending on the position of Recycler view

Tags: android, arraylist, android-recyclerview, kotlin, adapter

I want to open more details when I click on the item using the position and set the datils in the activity.

[image]

You can write your suggestion in Java or Kotlin :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Item click listeners for RecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32338910/item-click-listeners-for-recyclerview)

Comment: you can get the position from view holder click , and load the next page with that id

Comment: All those devs with no access to Google search, it's sad...

Comment: I didn't find any answer match my case :(

Comment: your case is not unique,btw  try solution of  first commenter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create Constructor in adapter class :

```
  public DataAdapter(List<Pojo> dataList, OnItemClickListener listener) {
            this.dataList = dataList;
            this.listener = listener;
        }
```

Create `OnBindViewHolder()` method and get position :

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final Pojo movie = dataList.get(position);

        holder.Showid.setText(movie.getCatagory_id());
        holder.fname.setText(movie.getCatagory_name());
        holder.thumbNail.setImageUrl(movie.getCatagory_thumbnailUrl(), imageLoader);
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override public void onClick(View v) {
                listener.onItemClick(movie.getSubCatagoryArrayList());
            }

        });
    }
```

In `MainActivity.class` create on Interface :

```
public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(ArrayList<Pojo2> item);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all recyclerView OnClick method to get position of Click item
like this method

```
int position=getAdapterPosition();
```

than get position of item (like `modelArrayList.get(getAdapterPosition());`)

than  send id to next activity and id to get data in database and set all the details in  next activity

final code

```
  itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int position=getAdapterPosition();
               ModelClass model = modelArrayList.get(getAdapterPosition());
              Long id = model.getId();
                Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), NextActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("id",id);

                v.getContext().startActivity(i);
            }
        });
```

and NextActivity code

```
Long id = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getLong("id", 0);
```